Omit NA values from a list - RScript for PowerBI
I am attempting to create a visulisation in PowerBI using Rscript. I am able to create a bar chart, however my biggest bar represents NA values. I am not sure how to omit these using R, other than my attempted way.
Code: `# dataset <- data.frame(ProductDescription__c.1, ProductDescription__c.2, ProductDescription__c.3, ProductDescription__c.4, ProductDescription__c.5)
# dataset <- unique(dataset)

# Paste or type your script code here:
library(tidyverse)

# Assuming you have loaded your dataset into 'dataset' already
# If not, you should load your data first

# Create a new column combining all product descriptions
dataset$product_description <- paste(dataset$ProductDescription__c.1, 
                                     dataset$ProductDescription__c.2, 
                                     dataset$ProductDescription__c.3, 
                                     dataset$ProductDescription__c.4, 
                                     dataset$ProductDescription__c.5, 
                                     sep = ", ")

# Remove leading and trailing whitespace
dataset$product_description <- trimws(dataset$product_description)

# Convert product description to UTF-8 encoding
dataset$product_description <- iconv(dataset$product_description, to = "UTF-8", sub = "byte")

# Split concatenated product descriptions
products <- dataset %>%
  select(product_description) %>%
  separate_rows(product_description, sep = ", ") %>%
  filter(product_description != "") %>%  # Filter out rows with blank product descriptions
  count(product_description) %>%
  arrange(desc(n)) %>%
  head(10)  # Adjust this number for the top N products you want to display

# Plot the top N products
options(repr.plot.width = 8, repr.plot.height = 6)  # Adjust width and height as needed
ggplot(products, aes(x = reorder(product_description, -n), y = n)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "skyblue") +
  labs(title = paste("Top", nrow(products), "Sold Products"),
       x = "Product",
       y = "Number of Sales") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))`



Thomasiko, it's going to be hard to help without providing a minimal reproducible example. Try something like dput(products) - also note minimal - much of your code is not useful, we just need the products data and the ggplot code

Not guaranteed without a minimal reproducible example, but try filter(product_description != "" & !is.na(product_description)). This should keep only rows which are not blank AND not NA, assuming your NAs are not literal character strings called "NA".
